# Force split chunk into certain bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have some scripts for a website. They are set up like this:

```
<!-- This script is loaded on every page -->
<script src="bundle1.js"></script>


<!-- This script is only loaded on certain pages -->
<script src="bundle2.js"></script>
```

Both `bundle1.js` and `bundle2.js` use jQuery. I use the `SplitChunksPlugin` so now a 3rd bundle is created: `common.bundle.js` that contains only jQuery. This is good obviously because now both bundles don't need jQuery in them.

However, since `bundle1.js` is loaded on every page, it would be nice if jQuery was just included in `bundle1`. How can I force Webpack to put jQuery only in `bundle1.js` and not `bundle2.js` and NOT split jQuery out into it's own common bundle that has to be downloaded separately?

Config:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    app: './js/app.js', // <-- loads on every page
    editor: './js/editor.js' // <-- loads on certain pages
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('./js'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      name: 'common'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can we see your webpack.config?

Comment: Added it. Pretty basic setup